# Website is showing http error 500, and all seems to correct in conf files

Tags: php, centos

I have a domain hosted in centos 7 which we have installed in ec2 instance
there was issue in the google warning few weeks back and now wee have uploaded the new fresh website files to the folder of the centos 7 server
in the google and firefox it is showing the error of google warning but when i go to edge browser it gives http 500 error
we have checked domain.conf files as well and it seems the correct one but still it gives the error

can someone help me to fix the issues?

Comment: Please include the error log information in your post to help us help you resolve this issue.

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: How to check the error log

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.